Goの単体バーティカルバー → | の使い方について知りたい
Goのunicode/utf8パッケージのソースを見ていたらこんな関数がありました。
func appendRuneNonASCII(p []byte, r rune) []byte {
    // Negative values are erroneous. Making it unsigned addresses the problem.
    switch i := uint32(r); {
    case i <= rune2Max:
        return append(p, t2|byte(r>>6), tx|byte(r)&maskx)
    case i > MaxRune, surrogateMin <= i && i <= surrogateMax:
        r = RuneError
        fallthrough
    case i <= rune3Max:
        return append(p, t3|byte(r>>12), tx|byte(r>>6)&maskx, tx|byte(r)&maskx)
    default:
        return append(p, t4|byte(r>>18), tx|byte(r>>12)&maskx, tx|byte(r>>6)&maskx, tx|byte(r)&maskx)
    }
}

switch文のcase文のreturnに append(p,t2|byte(r>>6)) とありますが、 | 一つだとどういった意味になるのでしょうか。条件分岐の || とも違うようですし。
ちなみにrune2Maxやt2はファイル内でこのように定数定義されています。
const (
    t1 = 0b00000000
    tx = 0b10000000
    t2 = 0b11000000
    t3 = 0b11100000
    t4 = 0b11110000
    t5 = 0b11111000

    maskx = 0b00111111
    mask2 = 0b00011111
    mask3 = 0b00001111
    mask4 = 0b00000111

    rune1Max = 1<<7 - 1
    rune2Max = 1<<11 - 1
    rune3Max = 1<<16 - 1

    // The default lowest and highest continuation byte.
    locb = 0b10000000
    hicb = 0b10111111

    xx = 0xF1 // invalid: size 1
    as = 0xF0 // ASCII: size 1
    s1 = 0x02 // accept 0, size 2
    s2 = 0x13 // accept 1, size 3
    s3 = 0x03 // accept 0, size 3
    s4 = 0x23 // accept 2, size 3
    s5 = 0x34 // accept 3, size 4
    s6 = 0x04 // accept 0, size 4
    s7 = 0x44 // accept 4, size 4
)

どなたかご教示お願いします。
質問でわかりにくい点などあれば教えていただければ幸いです。

& や | は整数型の数値データに対してビット単位で演算を行うときに使用する演算子で、& は "bitwise AND", | は "bitwise OR" です。 The Go Programming Language Specification: Arithmetic operators
